# Setting up parent attribute for catalog filters

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

I am currently working on a Magento site (v.1.9) that has 70 different product colors. This means that on the product index page, there is a massive list of colors for users to filter by on the left-hand column. We are worried that this is too many options for people to sift through.

Our colors are very specific, and realistically they could be grouped into "parent" colors. For example, we have "blush," "light pink," "salmon," etc, but those could all sit under the color "pink" for filtering purposes. Within the product detail page, however, we would want the actual color name to appear in the product color dropdown. Is there a way to create these parent color filters to appear in the left-hand column on the index pages?

I'm not a developer so layman's terms would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a work around on this. We've set up another attribute called "Color Family" for each product. There we can assign a parent color to each product without affecting the official color. We are only showing the "Color Family" attribute as filterable results. It works well.